# why captcha is not redendred after giving the error invalid captcha in php

Tags: php, captcha

When I fill the right answer for the CAPTCHA it works fine. After
giving the wrong answer it gives the alert message and then the CAPTCHA field
shows blank

```
<?php
session_start();
  $math='';
if(!isset($_POST['submit1']))
{
$digit1 = mt_rand(1,20);
    $digit2 = mt_rand(1,20);
    if( mt_rand(0,1) === 1 ) {

            $math = "$digit1 + $digit2";
            $_SESSION['ccanswer'] = $digit1 + $digit2;
    } else {

            $math = "$digit1 - $digit2";
            $_SESSION['ccanswer'] = $digit1 - $digit2;
    }
}

include('inc/subheader.php');
require "connection.php";

if(isset($_POST['submit1']))
{


        $xyzname=$_SESSION['XYZname'];
         $correct_answer=$_SESSION['ccanswer'];
        $answerRR=$_POST['answer1'];
         if($correct_answer==$answerRR){
            $sql="SELECT pwd FROM  logins WHERE username = '".$xyzname."' and encrypt_pwd='".$_POST['opwd']."'";
            $result1 = pg_query($pgcon,$sql);
            $num=pg_num_rows($result1);

            if($num>0)
            {

            $updatephoto ="UPDATE xyz set encrypt_pwd='".$_POST['npwd']."' where username='".$xyzname."'";
            pg_query($updatephoto);
            echo "<script>alert('Your password has been reset successfully!');</script>";
            }
            else
            {

                echo "<script>alert('Sorry, there is no match for that password.');</script>";
            }   

                        }else{

                            echo  "<script>alert('Invalid captcha');</script>";
                            $_SESSION['ccanswer']='';
                        }



            }
?>



    <form name="chngpwd" action="" method="post" id="demo">
                <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Old Password</label>
                  <input type="password" class="form-control" id="opwd" required placeholder="Old Password" name="opwd" onkeypress="return blockSpecialChar(event)">

                </div>
                 <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="exampleInputPassword1">New Password</label>
                  <input type="password" class="form-control" id="npwd" name="npwd" required placeholder="New Password" onkeypress="return blockSpecialChar(event)">

                </div>
                 <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Confirm Password</label>
                  <input type="password" class="form-control" data-rules-equalTo="#npwd" required id="cpwd" placeholder="Confirm Password" onkeypress="return blockSpecialChar(event)">

                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                 <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Captcha</label>
               <input id="answer1" name="answer1" type="text" placeholder="<?php echo $math; ?>" class="form-control" required="required" data-validation-required-message="Please enter Captcha Code."/>
                <p class="help-block text-danger"><?php if(isset($_GET['msg'])) { echo "Invalid Captcha Code.";}?></p>
                </div>
                 <div class="box-footer">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="submit1" value="Change Passowrd" >Submit</button>
              </div>
          </form>
```

I want CAPTCHA field not to be empty after giving the error message.

I didn't find the error but field shows empty under the CAPTCHA.

I tried to reload the page then its working fine but the form that was filled previously doesn't show the values.

Comment: Please read how to post a question on SO, and reformat your question this is unreadable.

Comment: Please check i reformat the question

Comment: You mean you want to pre-populate the text input field in which the user is supposed to enter the CAPTCHA solution, with the entered value again? _Why_? What use is that going to be, considering that you should be rendering a _new_ CAPTCHA in case of any form submission errors to begin with?

Comment: After filled the incorrect answer the captcha math is not calculation how user know about whats need to be fill

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the incorrect answer in the "value" field like this:

`... input type="text" value="<?php echo $variable;?>" ...`

I've also noticed you operate with SQL without variables escaping, which will definitely lead to SQL injection attacks.

Comment: Can you please tell me how i can use variable escaping to avoid injection attacks

Comment: I put the incorrect answer in the value field its show the incorrect answer on the field but how user know about the math which need to calculate because math variable show blank